# Limitar quantidade de caracteres de uma textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou simulando uma urna eletrônica em C#. Para limitar a entrada de dados,decidi criar um "teclado" de 0 a 9, para a inserção dos votos. Porém, estou com problemas para limitar a quantidade de caracteres na textbox, mesmo definindo o tamanho máximo para 2 caracteres, por exemplo, ao utilizar os botões o tamanho máximo da textbox é ignorado pelos botões, que adicionam textos infinitamente, o mesmo não acontece quando uso o teclado do computador. Há alguma forma de resolver isso?

Segue exemplo do código que estou utilizando e um print de como está meu formulário no momento:

```
 private void btnUm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        txtNum.Text +=  "1";

    }

    private void btnDois_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text+="2";
    }

    private void btnTres_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "3";
    }

    private void btnQuatro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "4";
    }

    private void btnCinco_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "5";
    }

    private void btnSeis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "6";
    }

    private void btnSete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "7";
    }

    private void btnOito_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "8";
    }

    private void btnNove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "9";
    }

    private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text += "0";
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode usar o evento [`TextBox_textChanged`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), assim sempre que um dígito for inserido na `textBox` você faz a verificação de tamanho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça a verificação na própria inserção.

Aliás, uma dica: se você for fazer exatamente a mesma coisa em todos os botões apenas alterando o texto, é possível apenas definir a propriedade **`Tag`** de cada botão como seu número e usar apenas um evento de click.

Assim você concentra a lógica em apenas um lugar e evita essa repetição toda.

Vide exemplo:

```
private void botaoUrna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int TamanhoMaximo = 2;

    var bt = (Button)sender;

    if(txtNum.Length < TamanhoMaximo)
        txtNum.Text += bt.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Ficou muito mais simples agora graças a essa dica da tag. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, basta você verificar se o tamanho excedeu o limite, caso tenha excedido então não adicionará a palavra. item

Segue o exemplo :

```
  private void botaoUrna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    const int TamanhoMaximo = 12;

    var bt = (Button)sender;

    if(txtNum.Length > TamanhoMaximo)
       return;
   }
```